# C++ prime number logic

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I'm creating a program that will output whether a number is prime or not. although, I'm trying to make it a little more complicated. I created a vector which I now want to store every prime number up to and including the number input by the user.

And then for the number input by the user (i.e. if the user types 13) will return true for the function hence it is a prime number. Here are some examples:

**U
        primechecker() : plist(2) {;}
        bool operator()(int);

3 5 7

then 3 5 6 7 7

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: 9 is not a prime number.

Comment: One problem is that 9 is not a prime number, but appears in the list.

Comment: If I input 13 immediately, it will simple just output  0 0 3. if I follow that up with a 15. it will output 0 0 3 5. where it should be, if I hit 13 it will output 3 5 7 11 13. then if I hit 15 it should output 3 5 7 11 13 15.

Comment: Apologies. Not sure why I put 9 in there.

Comment: "*whether a prime number is true or false*" Any prime number will evaluate to true since by definition they are not zero. You may want to change your wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your vector is starting with two zeros is because you are initializing it with two elements of the default constructor:

```
primechecker() : plist(2)
```

Check out the [documentation of std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) (you are using the 'fill constructor')

Comment: I removed that, and my output is now: (User): 3      |OUTPUT|: 3. (user): 13      |OUTPUT:| 3 3.  Any idea why it's not adding up all the previous prime numbers?

Comment: Check the logic of your algorithm. I'm not going to redo the entire thing for you.

Comment: Actually. I believe I just figured it out. Thanks though dude.